# How do I append and shuffle the list after obtaining the list from this function?(in Racket)

Tags: racket, shuffle

(define (zip a b)
(map list (list a b)))

> input-(zip '(1 2 3 4 5) '(a b c d e))
> '((1 a) (2 b) (3 c) (4 d) (5 e))

final output should append this list together and shuffle

was not able to get a valid result

Answer (score 1):

You should call `apply` with a list:

```
(define (zip a b)
  (apply map list (list a b)))

(zip '(1 2 3 4 5) '(a b c d e))
;; '((1 a) (2 b) (3 c) (4 d) (5 e))
```